# Rewriting without escaped output

Tags: nginx, escaping, url-rewriting

I have ported my "Gallery" to now be running behind my nginx instead of apache. "Everything works" except the following redirect:

```
rewrite ^/gallery2/v/([^\?]+)$ /gallery2/main.php?g2_path=$1 last;
```

This normally works, and my nginx logs show it works for most calls:

```
2015/05/10 12:27:43 [notice] 22192#0: *40455
          "^/gallery2/v/([^\?]+)$" matches "/gallery2/v/rolf/Shortlist/AAAMFL/",
          client: 192.168.a.b, server: example.com,
          request: "GET /gallery2/v/rolf/Shortlist/AAAMFL/ HTTP/1.1",
          host: "example.com",
          referrer: "https://example.com/gallery2/v/rolf/Shortlist/"
2015/05/10 12:27:43 [notice] 22192#0: *40455
          rewritten data: "/gallery2/main.php",
          args: "g2_path=rolf/Shortlist/AAAMFL/",
          client: 192.168.a.b, server: example.com,
          request: "GET /gallery2/v/rolf/Shortlist/AAAMFL/ HTTP/1.1",
          host: "example.com",
          referrer: "https://example.com/gallery2/v/rolf/Shortlist/"
```

The problem is that I have a few 'albums' with spaces in their names. In those cases, I get the following:

```
2015/05/10 12:33:02 [notice] 22191#0: *40489
          "^/gallery2/v/([^\?]+)$" matches "/gallery2/v/rolf/Shortlist/calendar+2013/",
          client: 192.168.a.b, server: example.com,
          request: "GET /gallery2/v/rolf/Shortlist/calendar+2013/ HTTP/1.1",
          host: "example.com",
          referrer: "https://example.com/gallery2/v/rolf/Shortlist/"
2015/05/10 12:33:02 [notice] 22191#0: *40489
          rewritten data: "/gallery2/main.php",
          args: "g2_path=rolf/Shortlist/calendar%2b2013/",
          client: 192.168.a.b, server: example.com,
          request: "GET /gallery2/v/rolf/Shortlist/calendar+2013/ HTTP/1.1",
          host: "example.com",
          referrer: "https://example.com/gallery2/v/rolf/Shortlist/"
```

When the URL has a space, the browser encodes it with a `+`, and requests:  `/gallery2/v/rolf/Shortlist/calendar+2013/` which is rewritten, essentially, to: `/gallery2/main.php?g2_path=rolf/Shortlist/calendar%2b2013/`

The above rewrite fails with an internal PHP error unable to locate the resource.... I can show, with the browser, and 'curl', that if I do not escape the `+` as `%2b`, that it works.....

In other words, the full URL:

```
/gallery2/main.php?g2_path=rolf/Shortlist/calendar+2013/
```

works, but the following does not:

```
/gallery2/main.php?g2_path=rolf/Shortlist/calendar%2b2013/
```

So, in my rewrite rule, how do I tell nginx to not escape the `+`?

As a reminder, here's my rule:

```
rewrite ^/gallery2/v/([^\?]+)$ /gallery2/main.php?g2_path=$1 last;
```